# How to get syslog in common event format (CEF)?

Tags: logging, syslog

I want `/var/log/syslog` in common event format(CEF). Is there any way to convert a syslog into CEF?

[image: Syslog sample]

Comment: What syslog daemon are you using?

Comment: It's rsyslogd .